# Unable to get Parameter with URL from another screen in react-native

Tags: react-native

I want to send the employee ID into another screen. but i can't get the id. It gets the default value id like i get 1 number id when i enter the 
    default value 1 just like i get 5 number id when i enter the default value 5. but actually i want get those employee id to see what administrator want.PLease check my code.

```
renderItem = ({ item}) => {
return (
  <View style={{flexDirection:'row',}}>
  <TouchableOpacity style={{height:70}} 
    onPress = {() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Employeeeeee' ,  {id : item.id })
    }>   
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, marginTop: 5, marginLeft: 15,color:'black',marginLeft:20 }}>
        {item.firstName}
      </Text>         
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 13, marginTop: 5, }}>       
        {item.profEmail}
      </Text>          
    </TouchableOpacity>
    </View> 
  )
 }

when i click on TouchableOpacity. I can't get the id as a parameter on below screen.

  componentDidMount() {   
   const id = this.props.navigation.getParam( 'id', 1) ;
   const url = 'http://104.197.28.169:3000/empProfile/' + id ; 
   fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    console.log("response " ,responseJson)
    this.setState({
       dataSource: responseJson , 
      isLoading: false
    })
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error)) 
  }

Here is my Navigation Code.

import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator} from 'react- 
navigation';
import AppContainer from '../App';
import ViewEmployeeLeave from '../Screens/ViewEmployeeLeave' ; 
import EmployeeProfile from '../Screens/EmployeeProfile' ;

  const eemployeeProfile = createStackNavigator(
  {employeedata  : EmployeeProfile},
  {
  defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
  title: 'Employee Profile',
  headerLeft: <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 
   navigation.navigate('Fourth')}>
     <Image style={{ width: 30, height: 30, marginLeft: 10 }}
      source={require('../icons/icons8-back-arrow-32.png')}></Image>
  </TouchableOpacity>,
  headerTintColor: '#fff',
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#008dff',
   },
   })
  },
 );
  export default createAppContainer(
 createSwitchNavigator({    
  AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
 loginnavigator: AppNavigator,
 Employeeeeee : eemployeeProfile,
  }),
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this

change

```
const id = this.props.navigation.getParam( 'id', 1) ;
```

to

```
const id = this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().getParam('id');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: sorry sir this code is not working for me.But Actually I get null message instead of Id,just like I get the same id as the number I entered instead of null. Please give me some ideas and check my code again.

Comment: As you are using nested navigator you need to get param from parent, will edit the answer check it.

Comment: Made changes check it now with new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ReactNavigation v5, you can destructure your values from `route` like this:

```
  const { id } = route.params;
```

See more information here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/